# Как разбить double на целое и нецелое число

Tags: c++, qt

Интересует метод, как разбить `double a = 52.993` на целое и число после запятой, не используя `std::string`.

т.е чтобы вывод был

```
52
0.993
```

Comment: Ну можно привести к int (это равносильно функции trunc), а потом вычесть из исходного целую часть, то есть `int integer = (int)x; double fractional = x - integer;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прямо в стандартной библиотеке есть готовая функция [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/). И там же пример

```
double param, fractpart, intpart;

param = 3.14159265;
fractpart = modf (param , &intpart);
printf ("%f = %f + %f \n", param, intpart, fractpart);
```